# Javascript worker throws an error when trying to use an arrow function

Tags: javascript, office-js, web-worker

I have a worker with the following code:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
  var r;
  r = doStuffInTheBackground(e.data)
  postMessage(r);
}, false);

function doStuffInTheBackground(val)
{
  return JSON.stringify(val);
}
```

which works perfectly fine but if write any code in the worker that uses an arrow function it throws an error. As an example, if I change that code to:

```
self.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
  var r;
  r = doStuffInTheBackground(e.data)
  postMessage(r);
}, false);

function doStuffInTheBackground(val)
{
  val = val.map(x => x);
  return JSON.stringify(val);
}
```

and when I try and run something I get a syntax error on the `>` in `val = val.map(x => x);` .

I am trying to run an office365 addin using officejs (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial) 
I dont know if this an issue with using arrow functions in workers or something else. I should note that that arrow functions only dont work in the worker in this project.

Comment: Sounds likely that office365 doesn't support ES6

Comment: I added more detail. Specifically, arrow functions work in all other files in the project. They only dont work when I try and use them in the worker. Does that make a difference to whether it supports ES6 or not?

Comment: Error! What is the error message???

Comment: @Palps - did you see this page?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins

Comment: can anyone tell me how he can use map(x=>x) ? I haven't seen any thing like this and i am trying to run this example it shows me null  !!!

Comment: Thanks @enhzflep  That seems to give me the answer.

Comment: @enhzflep Please make your comment about the documentation page an answer so this question will count as answered in Stack's statistics. Thanks.

Comment: @RickKirkham - I'm not going to do that. If you want to, answer it yourself. I was seeking clarification

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it does not support `ES6+`. If you require `ES6+` features, use a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), or just replace any `arrow functions` with regular `functions`.